# Save and Process huge amount of small files with spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, amazon-emr

I'm new in big data! I have some questions about how to process and how to save large amount of small files(pdf and ppt/pptx) in spark, on EMR Clusters.

My goal is to save data(pdf and pptx) into HDFS(or in some type of datastore from cluster) then extract content from this file from spark and save it in elasticsearch or some relational database.

1. I had read the problem of small files when save data in HDFS. What is the best way to save large amount of pdf & pptx files (maxim size 100-120 MB)? I had read about Sequence Files and HAR(hadoop archive) but none of them I don't understand how exactly it's works and i don't figure out what is the best.
2. What is the best way to process this files? I understood that some solutions could be FileInputFormat or CombineFileInputFormat but again I don't know how exactly it's works. I know that can't run every small file on separated task because the cluster will be put in the bottleneck case.

Thanks!

Comment: I have processed a PDF file on Hadoop Hope this below link helps http://ybhavesh.blogspot.in/2015/12/poc-sensex-log-data-processing-pdf-file.html (Note: Processing was done in Mapreduce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found some solutions for that small files problem in HDFS. I can use the following approaches:

1. HDFS Federation help us to distribute the load of namenodes: https://hortonworks.com/blog/an-introduction-to-hdfs-federation/
2. HBase could be also a good alternative if your files size is not too large.

> There are practical limits to the size of values (e.g., storing 10-50MB objects in HBase would probably be too much to ask); search the mailing list for conversations on this topic. All rows in HBase conform to the Data Model, and that includes versioning. Take that into consideration when making your design, as well as block size for the ColumnFamily.
>   https://hbase.apache.org/book.html

3. Apache Ozone which is object storage like S3 but is on-premises. At the time of writing, from what I know, Ozone is not production ready. https://hadoop.apache.org/ozone/

Answer (score 1):

If you use Object Stores (like S3) instead of HDFS then there is no need to apply any changes or conversions to your files and you can have them each as a single object or blob (this also means they are easily readable using standard tools and needn't be unpacked or reformatted with custom classes or code). 
You can then read the files using python tools like boto (for s3) or if you are working with spark using the wholeTextFile or binaryFiles command and then making a BytesIO (python) / ByteArrayInputStream (java) to read them using standard libraries.

2) When processing the files, you have the distinction between items and partitions. If you have a 10000 files you can create 100 partitions containing 100 files each. Each file will need to anyways be processed one at a time since the header information is relevant and likely different for each file.

Comment: How do you create these partitions?